# GIS scholarship sources

Tags: references

What are good sources to find GIS scholarships?

Comment: Converted this question to community wiki, as it lacks a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://gispathway.com/education/scholarships/) seems to have a nice list of GIS scholarships, and [Google is always helpful](http://www.google.co.il/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=GIS+scholarships) in such matters.

Answer (score 3):

Check with local chapters of GIS-oriented organizations, such as [GITA](http://www.gita.org) and URISA.  They often offer scholarships.

Comment: Quite true, I earned a small scholarship from my state's chapter of URISA

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind becoming part of the [Military Industrial Complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_industrial_complex), you could apply for a [SMART scholarship](http://smart.asee.org/).  The [NGA is a participant](https://www1.nga.mil/NGAJOBS/SPECIALEMPLOYMENT/Pages/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check within your discipline. Unless you're doing research in theoretical GIS. Really you should be looking at getting a scholarship in your domain (Transportation, Bio, Image analysis, etc.). All these fields have a heavy link to GIS so that broadens the scope of the search